# dnsmasq works in terminal, but not applications in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dnsmasq

I am attempting in effect to add `Server=/example.com/11.22.33.44` to the configuration of dnsmasq in order to route queries for example.com to a specific nameserver. To implement this I did the following.

- I comment out the line `dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and restarted network-manager
- I `apt-get install dnsmasq`
- I edit `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` to my needs and restart dnsmasq

From my *terminal*, tests like `host foo.example.com` work correctly. But all applications (e.g. Firefox, midori, remmina) seem to use the "old" settings (that is I see DNS queries go out and fail with `tcpdump`). I am lost how to merge automagic and manual settings like this.

**EDIT:** Meanwhile I have even tried unusual and desparate measures (e.g., rebooting) without success. Also it seems that the distinction is not reminal vs. other apps. Rather even in a single terminal session I observe

```
#host foo.example.com
foo.example.com has address 1.2.3.4
#ping foo.example.com
ping: unknown host foo.example.com
```

Ultimately,this led me to the solution. And admittedly this is an example where exaggerated anonymization made the question unanswerable: My domain in question is actually a subdomain of `.local`, which mdns steals away from proper dns. Editing `/etc/nsswitch.conf` solved the problem.

Comment: Why can't I answer my own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` so that the hosts line is

```
hosts: files dns mdns4
```